# Validar campo com CustomValidator

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tenho um campo que é preenchido com uma data automático , este campo e validado com customValidator para que a data não fique vazia, o problema quando o campo esta validado com vazio e clico em algum controle da pagina que da Postback, a validação ser perde.
É possível a cada post da pagina o campo ser validado pelo customValidator

Segue o código do controle:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDtInventario" CssClass="FormatacaoTextos" Style="width: 85px; margin-top: 3px;" Text="Dt. Inventário:" runat="server" />                    
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDtInventario" SkinID="CampoData" Style="float: left;"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator" ControlToValidate="txtDtInventario" ErrorMessage=" " Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="ValidarDataInventario" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="vgObrigarCampo"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Segue o código do validador:

```
function ValidarDataInventario(src,args) {
    args.IsValid = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDtInventario").value == "" ? false : true;
};
```

Comment: vc esta usando updatepanel?

Comment: Não estou usando o updatepanel

Comment: Amigo faz assim, troca o ValidateEmptyText="true" para false e controla a validação apenas na sua function JS.

Comment: RBoscini,  não deu certo a sua sugestão,  agora parou de fazer as validação ao trocar de true para false. obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema de validar o campo depois de dar postblack na pagina.

Foi feito em javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        ValidarDataInventario();
    });

    function ValidarDataInventario() {
        if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDtInventario") != null) {

            if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDtInventario").value == "") {
                $('#' + 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDtInventario').addClass('validationError'); 
            }
            else {
                $('#' + 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDtInventario').removeClass('validationError'); 
            }
        }
    }

 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDtInventario" SkinID="CampoData"  
                                Style="float: left;" onchange="javascript:ValidarDataInventario();" ></asp:TextBox>
```